# jQuery datepicker is initially opened

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have a problem on one of `datepickers`. Calendar initially stays opened.

[Here](http://codepen.io/FrenkyB/pen/rWKLvv?editors=1010) is example on code pen. Problem is only with the first datepicker, which initally stays open. I would like to have all datepickers closed initially. Snippet is below.

```js
$(function(){
  
  
  $("#inputTest").datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy", regional: "sl" }).datepicker("setDate",new Date());
  
  $("#inputTest1").datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy", regional: "sl" }).datepicker("setDate",new Date());
  
  $("#inputTest2").datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy", regional: "sl" }).datepicker("setDate",new Date());
  
  $("#inputTest").blur();
  
  
  
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<button>Test</button>

<br/>
<label id="lblDate"></label>

<input type="text" id="inputTest"/>


<input type="text" id="inputTest1"/>

<input type="text" id="inputTest2"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the focus from the input filed and hide the datepicker box

```
  $("#inputTest").blur();
  $('#ui-datepicker-div').hide();
```

```js
$(function(){
  
  
  $("#inputTest").datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy", regional: "sl" }).datepicker("setDate",new Date());
  
  $("#inputTest1").datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy", regional: "sl" }).datepicker("setDate",new Date());
  
  $("#inputTest2").datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy", regional: "sl" }).datepicker("setDate",new Date());
  
  $("#inputTest").blur();
   $('#ui-datepicker-div').hide();
  
  
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<button>Test</button>

<br/>
<label id="lblDate"></label>

<input type="text" id="inputTest"/>


<input type="text" id="inputTest1"/>

<input type="text" id="inputTest2"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hide the initial loading calendar in `document.ready` state.

```
 $("#ui-datepicker-div").hide();
```

Put the above line after all the calendars have intialized.